# Mysql 5.6 Partitioning on timestamp (with microseconds)

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I am playing around with mysql 5.6.
Im especially interested in the possibility:
A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision.

What i would like is to partition a table using such a timestamp.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `VALUE_BIS` (
  `TSTAMP` timestamp(3) NOT NULL,
  `ATTRIBUTE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VAL` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ATTRIBUTE_ID`,`TSTAMP`)
)  PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TSTAMP))
     (PARTITION p_s18 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-09-18 00:00:00')),
     PARTITION p_s19 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-09-19 00:00:00')),
     PARTITION p_Max VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-09-26 00:00:00' )));
```

==>ERROR 1491 (HY000): The PARTITION function returns the wrong type

*I think its normal as it returns unixtimestamp_seconds.microseconds which is not an integer*

If add the miliseconds like

```
PARTITION p_s18 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-09-18 00:00:00.000')
```

==> ERROR 1697 (HY000): VALUES value for partition 'p_s18' must have type INT

*OK same story as before*

If i change the definition of my tstamp column and do not use miliseconds

```
`TSTAMP` timestamp
```

==> It works just fine but i wont store my milliseconds and its not what i want.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't follow this remark:  *"...it returns . [sic] which is not an integer."*  Is that a typo or is something returning `'.'`?  If so, what?  My understanding was that UNIX_TIMESTAMP returned an integral value.

Comment: @pilcrow: Sorry i made a typo  and <>.<>  didnt display very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL still has some trouble partitioning tables with timestamps, [like this one, which can cause a InnoDB crash](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42849). They've done a few changes in the behaviour of [timestamp with fractional seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) in the past.

My first guess is that the way the fractual seconds are stored and used collides with the [unix_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp). Therefore the partitioning can't be created properly (because wrong type) ... and therefore generate the error messages you encounter.

A workaround would be to add a second field which only contains the timestamp without fractual seconds and use this instead as your range identifier.

Either way, you should report the bug.

Comment: They answered the bug (see link in my previous comment). I'll post it as a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update! So I wasn't too wrong with my assumption!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Bjoern i submitted a bug to the mysql tracker (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66958).
Here is their answer (for them its not a bug)

Timestamp(N) isn't supported as documented:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

" Incompatible change: In very old versions of MySQL (prior to 4.1), the TIMESTAMP data type supported a display width, which was silently ignored beginning with MySQL 4.1. This is deprecated in MySQL 5.1, and removed altogether in MySQL 5.5. These changes in behavior can lead to two problem scenarios when trying to use TIMESTAMP(N) columns with a MySQL 5.5 or later server:

When importing a dump file (for example, one created using mysqldump) created in a MySQL 5.0 or earlier server into a server from a newer release series, a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement containing TIMESTAMP(N) causes the import to fail with a syntax error."

Answer (score 0):

*This problem still exists for MySQL 8 and MariaDB 10.*

The above posts are correct about MySQL not being able to partition the fractions.
But you don't have to alter your table, you probably don't need to make partitions that granular.
It is possible by flooring the timestamp, this is a fast operation and works with any timestamp(N)

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE quarterly_report_status (
    report_id INT NOT NULL,
    report_status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    report_updated TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report_updated)) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-01-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-04-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Comment: I tested this configuration and found that partition pruning with inequity doesn't work. I filed a bug report to MySQL team in https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=112181&thanks=2&notify=3.